# THREE.js - Quaternion to lat, lon

Tags: three.js, geometry, quaternions, webvr

I am trying to convert vrDisplays rotation (comes in quaternions) to latitude and longitude, since an API I use needs the current rotation of the head mounted display in lat and lon values.

lordofducts answer in unity3D forums (https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/quaternions-and-euler-angles-to-longitude-latitude.154392/ )

gave me good hope that this is actually possible, but I am kind of stuck, as THREE.Quaternion doesn't seem to have ToAxisAngle() method and I am not that good with 3D geometry.

so does anybody have an idea how I can achieve this so I can do sth like that?

```
var quat = THREE.Quaternion();

quat.fromArray(vrDisplay.getPose().orientation);

var lat = //do sth with quat
var lon = //do seth with quat

api.rotateCamera({
    lat: lat, 
    lon: lon
});
```

// I noticed that in my code I already have a conversion from Euler angles to lat lon. So I might be just converting the Quaternion to Euler angles and then convert it to lat lon values. Still, there has to be a more sophisticated method...

Comment: (1) FYI, there is `Vector4.setAxisAngleFromQuaternion( quaternion )`. (2) But instead, try `v = new THREE.Vector3(); // reuse it! v.set( 0, 0, 1 ).applyQuaternion( quaternion );` That should give you the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var look = new THREE.Vector3();

quatToSpherical = function(quat){
  look.set(0,0,1);
  look.applyQuaternion(quat);
  look.normalize();
  if(Math.abs(look.x) < 0.001) look.x = 0.001;

  var angles = {};
  var radius = 1;

  angles.lat = Math.acos(look.z/r);
  angles.lon = Math.atan2(look.y , look.x);

  return angles;
}
```

The solution applies only to a standard cartesian coordinate system.

a right handed coordinate system with XY ground plane like I used in my setup needs offsets:

```
angles.lat = Math.acos(look.z/r) - Math.PI/2;
angles.lon = Math.atan2(look.y , look.x) - Math.PI;
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates